# mysqli_multi_query() issue when using MySQL variable

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm using an `mysqli_multi_query()` in my php script. The queries are:

```sql
SET @firstRow=1;
```

and

```sql
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(IF(@firstRow=1, CONCAT("Dear ", 
                              IF(@firstRow:=0, "", "")), "dear "), 
                                 parents.Salutation, "", parents.Lastname)
                    SEPARATOR ", ") AS Salutation
FROM parentChildRelation, parents 
WHERE parents.ID = parentChildRelation.ParentID 
AND parentChildRelation.ChildID = $childID
```

I know that this query is quite confusing, but it's the only way that I could get it to work (maybe someone has an idea for this, although this is not the purpose of this question)

My problem is that either `mysqli_next_result()` doesn't work properly or that somehow those queries don't work properly in an `mysqli_multi_query()` (it works in phpMyAdmin...) . Alternatively, which is most likely, I just made a mistake.

The relevant code in my php script is:

```
mysqli_multi_query($connection, $queries);
$result = mysqli_store_result($connection);
for($i = 0 ; $i < $queryNumber ; $i++) {
  mysqli_next_result($connection);
}
if($result) {
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    print($row[$varName] . "\n");
  }
}
```

While playing around with some `var_dump` I noticed that the result is `false`.

Also important: The code works fine when *$queries* is in fact only one query.

Comment: Is there a reason for the first query? Is it a simplified version? Or is it *actually* a one-line `SET` command? Why not pass it as parameter from PHP?

Comment: Yes, it's only one line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me it looks like a classic [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). As far as I understand your code, you want a result like "Dear Mr.Smith, dear Mrs.Smith" (Example: http://rextester.com/IGU41148). And the purpose of the `@firstRow` is to write the first "Dear" with uppercase "D".

Well.. A simplified query

```sql
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT("dear ", parents.Salutation, "", parents.Lastname)
                    SEPARATOR ", ") AS Salutation
FROM parentChildRelation, parents 
WHERE parents.ID = parentChildRelation.ParentID 
AND parentChildRelation.ChildID = $childID
```

would return something like "dear Mr.Smith, dear Mrs.Smith" (Example: http://rextester.com/BIF63982).

Now you could just use PHPs [`ucfirst(string $str)` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucfirst.php) which will return "*a string with the first character of **str** capitalized*" (Example: http://rextester.com/OZUI8315).

If you want to get the result using only SQL, you could Move the first "Dear" out of `GROUP_CONCAT` and use `, dear` as `SEPARATOR`

```sql
SELECT CONCAT("Dear ", GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(parents.Salutation, "", parents.Lastname)
                    SEPARATOR ", dear ")) AS Salutation
FROM parentChildRelation, parents 
WHERE parents.ID = parentChildRelation.ParentID 
AND parentChildRelation.ChildID = $childID
```

Example: http://rextester.com/HSFYF33827

Another way to avoid the `SET @firstRow=1;` line is to set the `@firstRow` variable in a joined derived table (`(select @firstRow:=1)`):

```sql
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(IF(@firstRow=1, CONCAT("Dear ", 
                              IF(@firstRow:=0, "", "")), "dear "), 
                                 parents.Salutation, "", parents.Lastname)
                    SEPARATOR ", ") AS Salutation
FROM parentChildRelation, parents, (select @firstRow:=1) initFirstRow
WHERE parents.ID = parentChildRelation.ParentID 
AND parentChildRelation.ChildID = $childID
```

Example: http://rextester.com/ULXR92492

As you can see, there are multiple ways to avoid the use of the `@firstRow` variable, and even more ways to avoid `mysqli_multi_query()`.

However I wouldn't use any of those solutions. What I would do is to execute a simple query

```sql
SELECT parents.Salutation, parents.Lastname
FROM parentChildRelation
JOIN parents ON parents.ID = parentChildRelation.ParentID 
WHERE parentChildRelation.ChildID = ?
```

and build the "Salutation" string in PHP. It doesn't matter much if you use a (`foreach`) loop or something like `array_map`. Most important is that you, your coworkers and any reviewer can read and understand your code fast and make necessary changes easily. So you should take the time to find a simple solution. It will probaly save you more time in the future.

Comment: Thank you! Normally it would ofcourse be the best solution to fix rhe string in a PHP script. In this case i'm actually selecting the query from another table. I'm doing this to replace keywords in a string with the result of a query, thats why the result of the query must be a finished string in a single row with only one (relevant) column. But the other queries should actually work. Thanks again!